# sql Two columns of one table references to the same column of the other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have two tables
table : Product where cost1_id is not null and cost2_id is nullable

```
   id    | cost1_id | cost2_id
   1     | 1        | 2
   2     | 3        |
```

table : Cost

```
   id    | value    | currency
   1     | 15       | EUR
   2     | 20       | USD
   3     | 100      | TND
```

I want to have this result without using join (I would rather work with UNION because I have large database)

```
product_id | cost1_value | cost1_currency | cost2_value | cost2_currency 
     1     | 15          | EUR            |  20         |  USD
     2     | 100         | TND            |             |
```

Comment: "I would rather work with UNION because I have large database" what is that mean ? Join is useless for large databases ?

Comment: `JOIN`s a a fundamental part of relational databases...

Comment: I have used JOIN  for large tables and the performance is dramatically decreased, but when I switched to union , the performance is enhanced (I mean the response time is faster)

Comment: Then you don't have the correct indexes, or your joins are obfuscating the RDBMS ability to use indexes.  I've provided two suggestions, one with a single join, *(but using `IN()` which will slow things down)* and one that just uses "traditional" joins.  I suspect the one you don't want to use is fastest.  As for the cases you encounter where `JOIN` is slow and you've made some use of `UNION` to speed it up, give a Specific example in another question and ask `Why is the non-join` version faster?  *(Remember to include both the SQL **and** sample data.)*

Comment: Please explain "without using join (I would rather work with UNION because I have large database)". Because it reflects severe misconceptions. For one thing, they do different things. UNION returns rows for which something OR something else is so. JOIN returns rows for which something AND something else is so.

Answer (score 4):

One option I can think of to *minimise* joins is...

```
SELECT
    product.id    AS product_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cost.id = product.cost1_id THEN cost.value    END)   AS cost1_value,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cost.id = product.cost1_id THEN cost.currency END)   AS cost1_currency,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cost.id = product.cost2_id THEN cost.value    END)   AS cost2_value,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cost.id = product.cost2_id THEN cost.currency END)   AS cost2_currency
FROM
    product
LEFT JOIN
    cost
        ON cost.id IN (product.cost1_id, product.cost2_id)
GROUP BY
    product.id
```

That said, the use of `IN()` may make that slower than just joining twice...

Ensure you have indexes on your tables.  ***They*** are the way to optimise joins, not trying to avoid them...

- In this case you probably only need a clustered primary key in the `Cost` table...

As such, I strongly recommend you *at least* **try** the "normal" way of doing this...

```
SELECT
    product.id    AS product_id,
    c1.value      AS cost1_value,
    c1.currency   AS cost1_currency,
    c2.value      AS cost2_value,
    c2.currency   AS cost2_currency
FROM
    product
LEFT JOIN
    cost    c1
        ON c1.id = product.cost1_id
LEFT JOIN
    cost    c2
        ON c2.id = product.cost2_id
```

***EDIT:***

Another esoteric option could be...

```
SELECT
    product_id,
    MAX(cost1_value)       AS cost1_value,
    MAX(cost1_currency)    AS cost1_currency,
    MAX(cost2_value)       AS cost2_value,
    MAX(cost2_currency)    AS cost2_currency
FROM
(
    SELECT
        product.id                                       AS product_id,
        cost.value                                       AS cost1_value,
        cost.currency                                    AS cost1_currency,
        CASE WHEN 1=0 THEN cost.value    ELSE NULL END   AS cost2_value,
        CASE WHEN 1=0 THEN cost.currency ELSE NULL END   AS cost2_currency
    FROM
        product
    LEFT JOIN
        cost
            ON cost.id = product.cost1_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        product.id                                       AS product_id,
        NULL                                             AS cost1_value,
        NULL                                             AS cost1_currency,
        cost.value                                       AS cost2_value,
        cost.currency                                    AS cost2_currency
    FROM
        product
    INNER JOIN
        cost
            ON cost.id = product.cost2_id
)
    unioned
GROUP BY
    product_id
```

Then create these indexes...

```
CREATE INDEX ix_product_cost1 ON product(cost1_id, id);
CREATE INDEX ix_product_cost2 ON product(cost2_id, id);
```

This ***might*** be slightly faster, but at the cost of significantly increased complexity which ***will*** become a maintenance headache in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Answer, This answer is for `SQL Server`. Try the same method in `PostgreSQL`.

```
CREATE table #Product(ID INT,Cost1_id INT,Cost2_id INT)
INSERT INTO #Product VALUES(1,1,1)
INSERT INTO #Product VALUES(2,3,0)

CREATE table #Cost(ID INT,Value INT,currency VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #Cost VALUES(1,15,'EUR')
INSERT INTO #Cost VALUES(2,20,'USD')
INSERT INTO #Cost VALUES(3,100,'TND')

SELECT ID product_id,MAX(cost1_value)cost1_value,MAX(cost1_Currency)cost1_Currency
        ,MAX(cost2_value)cost2_value,MAX(cost2_Currency)cost2_Currency
FROM(
    SELECT P.ID,C.Value cost1_value,C.Currency cost1_Currency,0 AS cost2_value,'' AS cost2_Currency
    from #Cost C, #Product P
    WHERE P.Cost1_id=C.Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT P.ID,0 AS cost2_value,'' AS cost2_Currency,C.Value ,C.Currency 
    from #Cost C, #Product P
    WHERE P.Cost2_id=C.Id
    )D
GROUP BY ID
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Please, please, please don't unnecessarily teach people to use ANSI-84 notation for joins.  It's been standard practice for over 20 years to use the `JOIN` keyword, and teaching people to use `,` instead is a dis-service to ***them***.  Besides you need a `LEFT JOIN` as some of the entries in `cost2_id` are `NULL`s.  And ***really*** don't start teaching the use of `(+)` for that, it's officially deprecated in SQL Server.

Comment: Yup, I just did this for, he said he can't use joins. Otherwise it should be a bad practice.

Comment: Using `,` ***IS*** using joins.  It's just shitty syntax to ***pretend*** that you're not.  It's a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: @MatBailie `,` is cross join with lower precedence than explicit joins. `,` as problem is an urban myth. `on` was necessary for outer joins. People *claim* that `,` can lead to more forgotton conditions than inner join. If you examine the difference, it is that inner join obliges you to have at least 1 condition per join--still not the correct number of conditions, let alone the right conditions. Moreover, it relies on the assumption that leaving out conditions is a problem, as if people don't test that their code actually does anything in particular. (If they don't, *that's* their problem.)

Comment: @philipxy - it's also technically acceptable to write all of your code on one line with no formatting, etc. That too is Poor Engineering for the exact same reasons. In either case I wouldn't allow any one's code past a review. Readability and ease of maintenance are not factors to be dismissed because a test framework should catch issues. I'm glad you don't work for me with that attitude.